# I am working on layering GIS over time axile to visualize vehicle's movement in time

Tags: spatio-temporal-data, time

I am trying to combine time and latitude/longitude dimensions by layering calendar over map and essentially creating time-space map showing how vehicle moves in time and over the roads. Anybody have any experience, what kind of application I can use?

Comment: I can't imagine a GIS package that cannot meet this requirement, which turns the question back to what GIS packages you have available.

Comment: Google Maps with Time Slider (Calendar) http://timemap.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.0.1/examples/basic_googlev3.html code https://code.google.com/p/timemap/

Comment: Car tracking/path animate Google Map http://jsfiddle.net/kSKGs/8/